# lwc lookup component not returning what I search for

Tags: apex, soql, query, lookup, dynamic-soql

I found a lookup component that I am using and so far was ok until last week. The user would like to type a word and all products with that word will be displaying.
example: when a user type CPC in the search input field, all product that has CPC in it will display. (Display-Other-CPC, Display-Auto-CPC, ...) Right now, the user needs to type Display-Other, Display-Auto,...) What Am I missing in the code?

Here is the code I am using

```
public class LwcLookupController {  
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)  
    public static List<sobject> findRecords(String searchKey, String objectName) { 
      string searchText = '\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchKey) + '%\'';  
      string query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM, ProductCode ' +objectName+ ' WHERE Name LIKE '+searchText+' LIMIT 10';  
      return Database.query('SELECT Id, Name, ProductCode FROM ' +objectName+ ' WHERE Name LIKE '+searchText+' LIMIT 10');
    }  
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have removed your leading wildcard.

```
String searchText = '\'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchKey) + '%\'';
//                     ^ MISSING
```

Comment: Ahhhh! I tried '\%' but was not working it is now working! thanks @Adrien Larson

Answer (score 0):

Always use binding so that we don't need to worry about SQL Injection and it also makes code more clean and readable.

```
public class LwcLookupController {  

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)  
    public static List<sObject> findRecords(String searchKey, String objectName) { 
        String searchText = '%' + searchKey + '%';
        String query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM, ProductCode FROM ' + objectName + ' WHERE Name LIKE :searchText LIMIT 10';
        /* Using binding here */
        return Database.query(query);
    }  

}
```